# How do you write "and" in very short form?

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a short form of *and* aside from *&*? For instance, *w/o* is a short form of *without*.

I used to write it but I forgot since I don't live in the US.

Comment: The word "and" is already short at 3 characters total. Except for "&", I don't think I've ever seen it abbreviated. I mean in some contexts you could interpret "/" as "and", or use the Latin "et" (as in "et cetera", "et al"), but that is far from common practice.

Comment: @Dan: there are lots of ways of handwriting &, although that's the only printed means. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) has some of them. Hopefully, I can find pictures somewhere.

Comment: The shortest form of *and* is "+". It's easier to write out than an ampersand, but the ampersand is the more common short *and*.

Comment: Look at Glyph Number 2 in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand#Writing_the_ampersand) with the top vertical line dropped and some of the lines straightened. It's essentially a "+" sign drawn without lifting your pen from the paper. That looks nothing like &, but I've seen it used. Maybe this is what you're thinking of.

Comment: In handwriting, I used to use a version of the glyph mentioned by @Peter Shor, bit without the top vertical stroke above the curve.  I think that used to be common in at least BrE before we all had keyboards.

Comment: Why do you want another symbol when "**&**" is universally understood?

Comment: There's the Tironian et, still used in Irish Gaelic and written **⁊**.

Comment: @medica: But for sets and logic, "+" (Boolean addition) is akin to "or" (set union, disjunction), and "*" (Boolean multiplication) is akin to "and" (set intersection, conjunction).

Answer (score 4):

May be you are looking for **'N'**. Like in "Rock **'n'** Roll".

Answer (score 4):

There is no commonly-accepted "short form" for "and", other than "&" (ampersand), or, more informally, "+" (plus).